# Find SSL version in TCP-packets in established TCP-connection

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp, tcpdump

is it possible to see the used SSL-Version in a TCP-dump in an established TCP-connection without killing the connection and re-establishing it to capture the "Client Hello"?
If yes, where can I find it?

BR and thanks in advance.

BTW: I also asked this question in the Network-engineering-Board. But as I need a quick answer to this question, I also post it here in order to reach more people. I hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. After the initial handshake everything is encrypted.

Comment: The version is negotiated during the handshake. After the handshake is finished, both parties are locked in to a specific version and everything is encrypted using that version, which is not identifiable in the encrypted packets themselves.